# ASP.Net - specified canvas download path is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written the following code to download a canvas image and it gets downloaded to the "Downloads" folder.
I want to specify the location so that it gets saved to a different location.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function CanvasToImage() {
          var dataURL = can.toDataURL('image/png');
          document.location.href = dataURL.replace("image/png", 
          "image/octet-stream");

          link.download = "test.png"; 
          link.path="D:\\TestPro\\TestPro\\TestPro\\PoloPro";      
          link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", 
                        "image/octet-stream");;
          link.click();
      }
</script>
```

I tried using "link.path" and it says the path is not accessible.
"TestPro" is the project where this JavaScript code is located.

Should I use the relative path instead ?
Can someone help me to convert it to relative path ? I'm too bad at relative paths.

Comment: Just follow this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647098/how-to-save-image-canvas-to-folder

Comment: Can you please help me to convert above path to relative path ?

Comment: You will have to use server side code to save the image to different folder.

Comment: if you are using razor view: link.path="@Url.Content("~/PoloPro")";